# Why does Firebase makes an extra map when updating values?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Why do I get the extra "0" map here? I just want to see the 0 and 1 followed by their value:

[image]

I upload the data as followed:

```
let channelItem = [
                "seed": [0, 0]
                ] as [String : Any]
            newGameRef.setValue(channelItem)
```

I update the value as followed:

```
 let intArray = randomIndex.map { Int($0)}
                var values = ["seed": [intArray]]
                print(intArray)
                self.gameRef!.updateChildValues(values)
```

The print says:

```
[14446, 76245]
```

How can it be that I get an extra map? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're inserting an array of intArrays instead of an intArray.

Replacing `var values = ["seed": [intArray]]` with `var values = ["seed": intArray]` should do it.